# How can I access Jack audio from Jitsi?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, microphone, jitsi, jack

I create jack audio connection using Cadence. But Jitsi not recognized the jack audio output. And Jitsi says failed to access microphone. I allow permission to camera and microphone but still failed.asoundrc file is above and I didn’t start pulseaudio. Because I dont want to use pulseaudio.

```
pcm.rawJack {
  type plug
  slave { pcm “jack” }
}

pcm.jack {
  type jack
  playback_ports {
     0 system:playback_1
     1 system:playback_2
  }
  capture_ports {
     0 system:capture_1
     1 system:capture_2
  }
}

ctl.mixer0 {
   type hw
   card 0
}
```

Cadence settings are in above picture.

[image]

Jitsi output is above. Audio output has not jack audio. And I used Chrome browser.

[image]